# PDF para texto organizando as colunas

Tags: r, pdf

Estou fazendo scraping para extrair arquivos `.pdf`, e preciso desses arquivos como um texto organizado, já que para cada linha de texto do arquivo encontram-se 3 colunas diferentes.

Por exemplo [neste arquivo](http://pesquisa.in.gov.br/imprensa/servlet/INPDFViewer?jornal=1&pagina=3&data=03/04/2017&captchafield=firistAccess), é possível ver as 3 colunas em questão.
Eu consigo ler o arquivo como `.txt` com o seguinte código:

```
library("rvest")
library("pdftools")

pdf_link <- "http://pesquisa.in.gov.br/imprensa/servlet/INPDFViewer?jornal=1&pagina=3&data=03/04/2017&captchafield=firistAccess"

# Inicia seção e acessa o .pdf
s <- html_session(pdf_link) %>%
  jump_to(pdf_link)

# Salva o arquivo como pdf e depois le
tmp <- tempfile(fileext = '.pdf')
writeBin(s$response$content,tmp)
doc <- pdf_text(tmp)
```

O problema é que cada linha do arquivo texto, estão presentes as 3 colunas separadas por espaços, e cada linha (com as 3 colunas) é separada por um `\r\n`.

O que eu gostaria era de separar as colunas para o texto fazer sentido.

A idéia que tive é:

- Separar as linhas até os `\r\n`
- Separar as colunas baseado no número de espaços (por exemplo: se existe uma sequencia de 5 espaços consecutivos, considera uma coluna).

Eu nunca mexi com strings e regex, por isso estou tendo dificuldades.
E eu vou precisar automatizar isso para vários arquivos, o que pode causar muitos erros por causa do número de espaços ou da disposição das colunas.

Se existir alguma outra solução baseada nas especificidades do `.pdf` também ia ser muito interessante.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Veja se isso ajuda:

```
doc1<-unlist(stringr::str_split(doc,"\\s{5,}|\n"))
c1<-paste0(doc1[seq(5,length(doc1),3)],collapse = " ")
c2<-paste0(doc1[seq(6,length(doc1),3)],collapse = " ")
c3<-paste0(doc1[seq(7,length(doc1),3)],collapse = " ")
```

Você pode tentar usar o pacote tabulizer também. Ele aparentemente supera as limitações de colunas com diferentes tamanhos:

```
library(tabulizer)
tmp<-tempfile()

url<-"http://pesquisa.in.gov.br/imprensa/servlet/INPDFViewer?jornal=1&pagina=2&data=03/04/2017&captchafield=firistAccess"

httr::GET(url,write_disk(tmp))

doc<-extract_text(tmp)
```

Comment: Muito bom, valeu

Comment: O `extract_text` já faz todo o serviço aparentemente. Muito obrigado

Answer (score 6):

A resposta do @José é ótima para a página em questão. Mas tente usar esse algoritmo na página 2 ou 10 e vai ver que as coisas saem um pouco do controle.

Isso ocorre porque nem todas as colunas tem o mesmo tamanho no DOU (um pressuposto na resposta do @José). No caso da página 2 a primeira coluna tem menos de 40 linhas e o texto restante se divide igualmente entre as duas colunas restantes ou mesmo porque o número de elementos de `doc1` que devem ser "pulados" - `doc1[1:4]` - variam.

Minha abordagem para este problema até o momento tem sido:

1. Abrir o `*.pdf` do DOU no Word e salvar como `*.txt` (isso pode ser automatizado de muitas formas, mas não conheço nenhuma pelo `R`).
2. Ler o `*.txt` com o `readLines()`. No `*.txt` criado pelo Word as colunas (sendo uma, duas ou três) são "empilhadas" de forma que você pode trabalhar mais facilmente com o texto.

A vantagem/desvantagem desta forma é que você confia no algoritmo da Microsoft para lidar com o `pdf`, que é muito melhor do que um que se possa criar rapidamente, mas escapa ao nosso controle.

Comment: Sim. Fui fazer os teste hoje de manhã e teve algumas falhas. O problema é que algumas linhas são somente espaços (embaixo de algum título por exemplo), e o algoritmo desconsidera essa linha, oq na hora de juntar as colunas, fica errado.
Achei muito interessante sua idéia, vou testar manualmente aqui e depois procurar se existe essa solução no R ou python. Valeu.

Comment: O pacote [pyWin32](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pywin32) do python pode ajudar.

Comment: Valeu! Fiz o teste aqui no word e funciona muito bem, foi uma ótima idéia.

Comment: Editei minha resposta para usar o tabulizer. Testei com a página 2 e funcionou. Além disso, simplifiquei o código que você usou para scraping.